# Struts 1.2 Session Reset

Tags: java, session, struts

I have an app that authenticates prior to authentication (not good). I need to reset the session cookie after authentication and bind to a user. Is this feasible / possible using http sessions in java?

Comment: I don't understand the actual issue; wouldn't you set a user object (or whatever) in session after authentication, and check that? What's in session *before* "authentication"? How can something authenticate authentication?

Comment: Sorry, correction *sets a session token prior to authentication.

Comment: That doesn't strike me as being as a problem; there's a session created as soon as any JSP is hit.